# How i can replace these words with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, replace

I want to rename CAR BUS to MY CAR, rename WATER to BREAKFAST, and delete the cocacola and fanta, to now be shown. People tell me it must be replaced with JS but I have no idea.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  CARS BUS<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/development/#current-developments">WATER</a></li>
    <li><a href="/development/#future-developments">COCA COLA</a></li>
    <li><a href="/development/#past-developments">FANTA</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Plain JS
// `document.querySelector` will get the first element that matches
// inside selector `>` means that you want to get the direct child of --- in this case `.dropdown`
var $carbus = document.querySelector( 'li.dropdown > a' ), // element
    $dropdownMenu = document.querySelector( '.dropdown-menu' ), // dropdown-menu
    $firstLi = $dropdownMenu.querySelector( 'li > a' ), // element with water text
    $notFirstLi = $dropdownMenu.querySelectorAll( 'li:not(:first-of-type)' ); // last two `li` items

replaceWord( $carbus, 'cars bus', 'my car' ); // replacing `cars bus` with `my car`
replaceWord( $firstLi, 'water', 'breakfast'  ); // replacing `water` with `breakfast`

// removing last two items
$notFirstLi.forEach(function (item) {
    item.remove();
});

/**
 * @param {Element} el - target element 
 * @param {String} oldWord - Old word you want to change
 * @param {String} newWord - New word you want to show
 */
function replaceWord(el, oldWord, newWord) {
    var re = new RegExp( oldWord.toUpperCase(), 'i' ),
        newTxt = el.innerText.replace(re, newWord.toUpperCase());
    el.innerText = newTxt;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">CARS BUS<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/development/#current-developments">WATER</a></li>
        <li><a href="/development/#future-developments">COCA COLA</a></li>
        <li><a href="/development/#past-developments">FANTA</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the underlying HTML, there's no need to use JavaScript at all. So *if you have access*, change it in the HTML.

In case you *don't have* access, you have to do these steps:

1) Grab elements to change with a DOM query (`document.querySelector` & `document.querySelectorAll`)

2) Change their `innerHTML` to the desired text

Based on the HTML you've shown, the most tricky part of it will be the DOM query. Mainly because there isn't much which allows to identify the correct elements (via `id` or `class`). To find out if you are working with the correct elements, you also have to compare their content.

This should work:

```js
function queryAll(s, r) {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call((r || document).querySelectorAll(s));
}

function isTarget(needle, element) {
  var regex = new RegExp(needle);
  return regex.test(element.innerHTML);
}

function changeText (needle, replacement, element) {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(needle, replacement);
}


var dropdowns = queryAll('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]');
dropdowns.forEach(function (anchor) {
  if (isTarget('CARS BUS', anchor)) {
    var subAnchors = queryAll('a', anchor.nextElementSibling);
    changeText('CARS BUS', 'MY CAR', anchor);
    subAnchors.forEach(function (sub) {
      if (isTarget('WATER', sub)) {
        changeText('WATER', 'BREAKFAST', sub);
      } else {
        sub.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  CARS BUS<b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/development/#current-developments">WATER</a></li>
    <li><a href="/development/#future-developments">COCA COLA</a></li>
    <li><a href="/development/#past-developments">FANTA</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const :( maybe about lowercase? Is Water instead of WATER

Comment: Yes @David it isn't working because of this issue,. In fact is Water not WATER and with lowercase it isn't working, how i must modify code to make it work?

Comment: If it says "Unexpected token const", it means your browser can't understand ES6. I'll update my answer

Comment: @EvgeniyUdemy If you want to change "WATER" to "Water", find this line and edit it: `changeText('WATER', 'BREAKFAST', sub)`